# Mysql not updating the values in table

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am doing a Python Django project with MySQL workbench.  I was originally getting the following error when clicking one of the search buttons in my app:

```
DatabaseError at /search/results/mobiles/
  (1214, "The used table type doesn't support FULLTEXT indexes")
```

Then I changed the database engine from `INNODB` to `MYISAM`, by issuing the query:

```
SET GLOBAL default_storage_engine=MYISAM;
```

That got past the original error.  But now if I make changes in Django admin UI (localhost:8000/admin), the MySQL table values do not get altered.  How do I fix this problem?

This is my search_category and search_result definition:

```
def search_in_category(request, slug):
    # reset the search params, if present
    try:
        del request.session['search']
    except KeyError:
        pass

    return search_results(request, slug)

def search_results(request, slug):
category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=slug)
fields = list(category.field_set.all())
fields += list(Field.objects.filter(category=None))
fieldsLeft = [field.name for field in fields]

if request.method == "POST" or 'search' in request.session:
    ads = category.ad_set.filter(active=True,
                                 expires_on__gt=datetime.datetime.now())
    # A request dictionary with keys defined for all
    # fields in the category.
    post = {}
    if 'search' in request.session:
        post.update(request.session['search'])
    else:
        post.update(request.POST)

    sforms = prepare_sforms(fields, fieldsLeft, post)

    isValid = True

    for f in sforms:
        # TODO: this assumes the form is not required
        # (it's a search form after all)
        if not f.is_valid() and not f.is_empty():
            isValid = False

    if isValid:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            request.session['search'] = {}
            request.session['search'].update(request.POST)
            return redirect('classifieds_browse_search_results', slug=slug)

        for f in sforms:
            ads = f.filter(ads)

        if ads.count() == 0:
            return render_to_response('classifieds/list.html',
                                      {'no_results': True,
                                       'category': category},
                                      context_instance=RequestContext(request))
        else:
            context = context_sortable(request, ads)
            context['category'] = category
            return render_to_response('classifieds/list.html', context,
                                      context_instance=RequestContext(request))
else:
    sforms = prepare_sforms(fields, fieldsLeft)

return render_to_response('classifieds/search.html',
                          {'forms': sforms, 'category': category},
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is self explanatory, you are trying to index a FULLTEXT field in InnoDB.  Ask yourself this question, how does a computer index a FULLTEXT field?

InnoDB is a great engine.

Remove the index from the FULLTEXT field to fix the problem from occurring on the InnoDB engine.

Comment: I am not using any FULLTEXT field in my table

Comment: whichever view is using "/search/results/mobiles/" is calling something incorrectly in the DB

Answer (score 0):

after the alter table to `MYISAM` ==> *problem raised here*

your table is locked that's why you can't able to alter the table value via admin. first check your table is locked or not using below command.

```
show open tables WHERE Table LIKE 'tb_geetha' AND In_use > 0
```

if `locked` then `mysql> UNLOCK TABLES;`